# REGEX for combined alphanumeric ONLY strings of indeterminate length

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

We have an integration that is failing when special characters are included in certain text fields.  I found

```
NOT(REGEX(fieldName__c, "[a-zA-Z0-9]"))
```

which works fine for a single character/digit, but failed with two or more.  And I need to include spaces (and ignore the field when blank).

Answer (score 0):

The following basic structure works, limiting to (from left to right)
spaces, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and numerals,
and to allow combinations (and not just a single character), the * after the closing ']':

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(fieldName__c)),
    NOT(REGEX(fieldName__c, "[ a-zA-Z0-9]*"))
)
```

Comment: You do not need the ISBLANK test if you use "+" instead of "*". Please note this is rather basic regex, easily found  through the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_regex.htm&type=5). Additionally, if you wish to allow other forms of whitespace, use the `\s` character class instead of the literal space. Finally, you can avoid NOT by negating the regex, using `^` in the character class `[]` you defined.